# how can i change label status from my own data set in text classification

Tags: python

I am beginner in data science field the problem I faced is how can I change my label status from my code I want my label status is similar to my file names which is in the length of 5 and all are in csv format

I tried to make a dictionary to set label according to my filenames but I cant..

```
idDic = {1: 'Acta Informatica.csv', 2: 'AI & SOCIETY.csv', 3: 'Algorithmica.csv',
     4: 'Annals of Mathematics and Artificial Intelligence.csv',
     5: 'Applicable Algebra in Engineering, Communication and Computing.csv'}
labels=[]
texts=[]
for key in idDic:
    u = key
    t = idDic[key]
  for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    content=line.split()
    labels.append(u[0])
    texts.append(" ".join(content[1:]))

trainDF = pandas.DataFrame()
trainDF['texts'] = texts
trainDF['label'] = labels
print(trainDF)
```

'f p' is filename which is already in a merged form of 5 files..
I expect the output of my code is my label status match with the dictionary keys and according to that key my files set in a data frame

Comment: Why do you do `t = idDic[key]` when `t` is never used? and why do `u = key`, why not just use `key`?

Comment: I used it in rest of the code the main problem is occur in nested for loop

Comment: Can you show an example on what a text file contains? just a few lines are enough

Comment: I used csv files in which all contents is related to published computer science article and all 5 files used as an single csv file in code But the actual problem is arise on setting the labels. I already set the Text data frame but label data frame not give accurate output as I want...

Comment: well, you are using `u[0]` and not `content[0]`, try using this: `labels.append(content[0])`

Comment: it give an error list Index out of range

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/    I follow this links but used my own data set and some code changes as I mentioned above code area... In website link the data set is already set in text or label format but in my case I have to set it...

Comment: That guide even explicitly have `labels.append(content[0])` under section 1. the only reason you can get index out of range is if you have empty lines

Comment: My dataset already set in full format no empty line exist in my dataset... But if I used the   u[0]  then I found the label value for all the files is one which is not my requirement.